# Problem with an event registering multiple times

Tags: javascript

Currently I have it set to "if true == true" just to simplify because the problem isn't there.

```js
switchBoxes(player){
    if (true == true){
        document.addEventListener("keypress", function switchListen(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 101) {
                console.log("TrapActivated");
            }
        }, {once:true});
    }
}
```

I have a problem in my game that I am making in javascript where I see "TrapActivated" hundreds of times in the console when I only press the key 'E' once. switchBoxes is a function in a class called collisionObjects. It is meant to create a box that acts as a switch and effects some other part of the map I created when you press the key 'E'. The player is able to move around the map freely around the canvas. Instead of "if true == true", I had collision detection for the player to see if he was touching the switch. The parameter 'player' is so that you can choose who is able to use that switch. When I press 'E', the console gives me anywhere from around 34 to 500 messages. It stops very soon after I have pressed 'E', around 100-200 milliseconds later. And I haven't done anything with the framerate, so it should be whatever the default is.

This is my first question on this site so please forgive me if it is not as specific as it should be.

Comment: how many times do you call `swichBoxes`? If you call it many times, you will register the event many times.

Comment: What browser are you using? A lot of them support the `once`-option, but not all (most notably IE). See here for a list of browsers that support this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). I'm not fluent in JavaScript, but can you use an event like `onkeydown`? I'm guessing you are using a function like `onkeypress` (see [onkeydown Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) instead of `event.keyCode`;

Second - Your `switchBoxes()` function create new listener on every call;
So it's absolutely correct behaviour. For avoid this You can try to use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). But, in My opinion, the best way in this case - declarate `switchListen` in parent scope. Something like:

```js
function switchListen(event) {
    if (event.key === 'e') {
        console.log("TrapActivated");
    }
}

function switchBoxes(player){
    if (true == true){
        document.addEventListener('keypress', switchListen, {once:true});
    }
}
```

So, You'll create the only one listener, that will be removed at first call because of `once:true`;

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone who commented to help solve my problem! Have a wonderful day and God bless!